# SharePoint threw "Unknown SQL Exception 206 occured." Anyone familiar with this?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

Our SharePoint instance threw the following errors when attempting to access data through a Content Query Tool:

```
04/02/2010 10:45:06.12  w3wp.exe (0x062C)                           0x1734  Windows SharePoint Services     Database                        5586    Critical    Unknown SQL Exception 206 occured. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with datetime   
04/02/2010 10:45:06.25  w3wp.exe (0x062C)                           0x1734  Office Server                   Office Server General           900n    Critical    A runtime exception was detected. Details follow.  Message: Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with datetime  Techinal Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with datetime     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData(...  
04/02/2010 10:45:06.25* w3wp.exe (0x062C)                           0x1734  Office Server                   Office Server General           900n    Critical    ...)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlC   
04/02/2010 10:45:06.25  w3wp.exe (0x062C)                           0x1734  CMS                             Publishing                      8vyd    Exception   (Watson Reporting Cancelled) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with datetime     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteRead...  
04/02/2010 10:45:06.25* w3wp.exe (0x062C)                           0x1734  CMS                             Publishing                      8vyd    Exception   ...er(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, ...   
04/02/2010 10:45:06.25* w3wp.exe (0x062C)                           0x1734  CMS                             Publishing                      8vyd    Exception   ...CommandBehavior behavior)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean& bSucceed)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CrossListQuery(String bstrUrl, String bstrXmlWebs, String bstrXmlLists, String bstrXmlQuery, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pCallback, Object& pvarColumns)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CrossListQuery(String bstrUrl, String bstrXmlWebs, String bstrXmlLists, String bstrXmlQuery, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pCallback, Object& pvarColumns)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetSiteData(SPSiteDataQuery query)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedArea.GetCrossListQuery(SPSiteDataQuery query, SPWeb currentContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CrossListQueryCache.GetSiteData(CachedArea cachedArea, SPWeb web, SPSiteDataQuery qu...   
04/02/2010 10:45:06.25* w3wp.exe (0x062C)                           0x1734  CMS                             Publishing                      8vyd    Exception   ...ery)  
04/02/2010 10:45:06.25  w3wp.exe (0x062C)                           0x1734  CMS                             Publishing                      78ed    Warning     Error occured while processing a Content Query Web Part. Performing the following query '<ViewFields><FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Nullable="True" Type="Text"/><FieldRef ID="{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb}" Nullable="True" Type="Lookup"/><FieldRef ID="{1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1}" Nullable="True" Type="Counter"/><FieldRef ID="{28cf69c5-fa48-462a-b5cd-27b6f9d2bd5f}" Nullable="True" Type="DateTime"/><FieldRef ID="{1df5e554-ec7e-46a6-901d-d85a3881cb18}" Nullable="True" Type="User"/><FieldRef ID="{d31655d1-1d5b-4511-95a1-7a09e9b75bf2}" Nullable="True" Type="User"/><FieldRef ID="{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}" Nullable="True" Type="DateTime"/><FieldRef Name="PublishingRollupImage" Nullable="True" Type="Image"/><FieldRef Name="_Level" Nullable="Tr...  
04/02/2010 10:45:06.25* w3wp.exe (0x062C)                           0x1734  CMS                             Publishing                      78ed    Warning     ...ue" Type="Number"/><FieldRef Name="Comments" Nullable="True" Type="Note"/><FieldRef ID="{8c51f6d2-5908-4844-a4c0-abd7728feb7c}" Nullable="True" Type="Choice"/><ProjectProperty Name="Title"/><FieldRef Name="ScopeId" /><Field
```

The farm is MOSS 2007 with SQL Server 2005 backend.

Any ideas are welcomed.

Dale

Comment: Can we see the rest of your query? That's the kind of error SQL throws if you do something like ORDER BY CASE or SELECT CASE WHEN and have different return data types for which implicit conversion isn't supported (See, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

Comment: Since it's internal to SharePoint, I don't know what the actual SQL Query is.  I can do a trace on the SQL Server and see what happens there.